# Why does my JFrame username/password program declare every login successful?

Tags: java

Whenever I place any input into the username/password fields I always get a success. I tried renaming the variables with an additional 1 to see if the problem was that I accidentally made them all equal to each other. I don't think that was the case. Simple program I know but I can't find where it went wrong.

```
package guiPack;

import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;

public class LoginFrame extends JFrame implements ActionListener {

    Container container = getContentPane(); // If the code is part of a JFrame, you must use getContentPane
    JLabel userLabel = new JLabel("Username"); // I believe that this part is pretty self-explanatory 
    JLabel passwordLabel = new JLabel("Password");
    JTextField userTextField = new JTextField();
    JPasswordField passwordField = new JPasswordField();
    JButton loginButton = new JButton("LOGIN");
    JCheckBox showPassword = new JCheckBox("Show Password");
    JButton rulesButton = new JButton("Rules");
    JButton createAccButton = new JButton("Register Account");

    LoginFrame() {
        setLayoutManager();
        setLocationAndSize();
        addComponentsToContainer();
        addActionEvent();
    }

    public void setLayoutManager() {
        container.setLayout(null);
    }

    public void setLocationAndSize() {
        userLabel.setBounds(50, 150, 100, 30);
        passwordLabel.setBounds(50, 220, 100, 30);
        userTextField.setBounds(150, 150, 150, 30);
        passwordField.setBounds(150, 220, 150, 30);
        showPassword.setBounds(150, 250, 150, 30);
        loginButton.setBounds(80, 300, 200, 30);
        rulesButton.setBounds(130, 50, 100, 30);
        createAccButton.setBounds(80, 350, 200, 30);    
    }

    public void addComponentsToContainer() {
        container.add(userLabel);
        container.add(passwordLabel);
        container.add(userTextField);
        container.add(passwordField);
        container.add(showPassword);
        container.add(loginButton);
        container.add(rulesButton);
        container.add(createAccButton);
    }

    public void addActionEvent() {
        loginButton.addActionListener(this);
        showPassword.addActionListener(this);
        rulesButton.addActionListener(this);
        createAccButton.addActionListener(this);
    }    

    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent myactionevent) {
        if (myactionevent.getSource() == loginButton) {
            String usernameText;
            // String passwordText; THIS DOES NOT WORK (PART OF THE BELOW COMMENT CODE)
            usernameText = userTextField.getText();
            // passwordText = passwordField.getText(); THIS DOES NOT WORK OR HAS A WARNING BECAUSE THE PASSWORD IS STORED AS A STRING AND IS NOT IN MEMORY. ALTERNATIVE IS USING THE BELOW
            String passwordText=String.valueOf(passwordField.getPassword());
            if (usernameText.equalsIgnoreCase(usernameText) && passwordText.equalsIgnoreCase(passwordText)) // In order to get this part to work you must remove the pre-set password and set it to the string you got from the register below
            {
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(this, "Login Successful");
            } 
            
            else 
            {
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(this, "Invalid Username or Password");
                userTextField.setText("");
                passwordField.setText("");
            }    
        }
        
        if (myactionevent.getSource() == showPassword) {
            if (showPassword.isSelected()) {
                passwordField.setEchoChar((char) 0);
            } else {
                passwordField.setEchoChar('*'); //this will hide all the characters in the password field
            }
        }
        if (myactionevent.getSource() == rulesButton) {
        //  if (rulesButton.isSelected()) THIS DOES NOT WORK!
            {
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(this, "Here are the rules!"
                        + "1. If username and password are correct, success!"
                        +"2. If username and password do not match, incorrect!" + "3. Password must include a special character"); // I am not sure why this is not working. I wanted it to be a row. 
            }
        }
        
        if (myactionevent.getSource() == createAccButton) {
            String usernameText = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Enter a username!"); // Option to input a username
            String passwordText = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Enter a password!"); // Option to input a password
        }
    }    
}


    class Login // This is the general windows frame
    {
    public static void main(String[] a) 
    {
        LoginFrame frame = new LoginFrame();
        frame.setTitle("Login Form!");
        frame.setVisible(true);
        frame.setBounds(600, 100, 360, 450);
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.setResizable(true);

    }
    }
```

Comment: how would you expect this to return anything but true? if (usernameText.equalsIgnoreCase(usernameText) && passwordText.equalsIgnoreCase(passwordText))

Comment: Your code does exactly what it should do, but it doesn't make sense. You are comparing two fields with themselves, they should be compared by either hardcoded values, or values in a DB, or, better yet, a hashCode of those fields should be compared to a hashCode in the DB

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
if (usernameText.equalsIgnoreCase(usernameText) 
  && passwordText.equalsIgnoreCase(passwordText))
```

There is your problem:

You are comparing usernameText to itself, not to a value, the same with passwordText.

Start by adding hardcoded values in your class:

```
private static final String username="USER";
private static final String password="pAssw0rd";
```

Then, change that line to:

```
if (username.equals(usernameText) 
  && password.equals(passwordText))
```

Don't use `equalsIgnoreCase` here, and if you use it, don't use it for passwords. "pAssWoRd" is not the same as "password", nor should it be treated as the same.

If you do this, you'll see that now your input is validated against those fields, any other input will render the login invalid.

EDIT:
As for this part:

```
if (myactionevent.getSource() == createAccButton) // This section of code adds functionality to my Register button
        {
            String usernameText = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Enter a username!"); // Option to input a username
            String passwordText = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Enter a password!"); // Option to input a password
        }
```

These are local variables, that only exist within the scope of this if-block, so you can't use them outside of this if block.

EDIT 2:

```
//  if (rulesButton.isSelected()) THIS DOES NOT WORK!
```

Actually, that works just fine, but just because you clicked a button, doesn't make it selected.

Seeing as you already know that that button is clicked, what more do you need?

Comment: Thank you, I understand now how silly it was for me to use IgnoreCase and setting the variables = to each other and expecting anything else. I forgot about the local variables and how I can't call them because of the if block

Comment: @markinator what you can do, is have that JOptionPane set instance or static variables, those are at class level, so those you would be able to use.

Comment: When trying to use the private static final I receive an illegal modifier error; only final is permitted

Comment: @markinator that is most likely because you put it in a method, I intended it to be on class level. It's indeed impossible to use private or static in a method, but this you should have already learned before switching to UI programming.